# Unable to export any of my projects into a .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, compiler-errors, export

Everytime I try to export any of the projects from my workspace into a Java jar file, I end up with an error:

> JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
>     Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 'Server Manager/src/me/Zahach/ServerManager/main.java'

And this error is repeated for every class in my project.

I tried reinstalling Eclipse, that didn't work.
I then tried to recreate a project and drag and drop my packages into it, that didn't work either.

What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding those projects before exporting?

Comment: @Banthar Yep did everything i could

Comment: @Banthar The problem is coming from the java libraries where dns_sd.jar is missing.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall JAVA? I hope that would help.

Comment: @LoganathanMohanraj I did reinstll it already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused because of a missing `.class` file(s) for corresponding `.java` file(s)

1. **In Eclipse**

   Goto `Project->Clean` and `Rebuild` the Project and then try exporting,
   If it doesn't work then make sure `.class` file exists in the bin folder for `main.java` file in
   your case
2. Another solution is to ensure that the [Classpath is Valid](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that the permissions in your workspace folders are ok. I ran into this problem after updating Eclipse and then downloading some Maven dependencies.
In the end, what fixed it was doing a `sudo chmod 777 -R workspace/MyProject`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem while exporting my java files into a compressed jar file, so I checked the Java Build Path of my project and found that the External jars I was referring to from the project are not present in the designated folder locations. Once I have resolved that, I was able to export my java files into a jar.

Answer (score 0):

You may have any java file that is totally empty. You have that file in project with somethingName.java but inside it is nothing. So no bytecode gets generated for it and it throws an error. You can find that file in error details and delete it and try building jar again. It works :) Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

I had empty Java file classes causing the error.